# If the expected value of $X^n$ is $n!$, what is the probability density function of the random variable $X$?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, gamma-function, exponential-distribution

I am working through my homework and this problem has me stumped. I don't know how  to come up with a pdf just by being given an expected value? We are learning about exponential distributions, but this detail isn't stated. Is that because simply the fact that the function is $X^n$ implies it's an exponential distribution? I am also wondering if it has to do with the gamma function because I know that $$E[X^s] = \frac{\Gamma(s+1)}{\gamma^s}.$$ Any direction at all would be greatly appreciated as I am thoroughly confused.

Comment: No, the fact that you are given information about $X^n$ does not say anything about whether it's an exponential distribution: you can measure the expected value of $X^n$ for any distribution (although it may not always be a convergent integral).

Comment: As for the gamma distribution, yes, you should give some thought about how you might choose parameters for the gamma distribution so that the given data matches the predicted value of $E[X^s]$.

Comment: More generally, given the values of $E[X^n]$ for all $n$ you can always recover the [moment generating function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment-generating_function) which can potentially be used to identify the distribution.

Comment: The last edit makes no sense, I am reverting it.

Comment: To your comment about recovering the MGF, I know that M(t) of E[X^n] is just the moment generating function to the nth derivative, but I don't know where to go for there? Also, I forgot to mention that the problem specifies that n starts at and goes up by 1 infinitely, and that may be of importance.

Comment: I think you are still a bit confused.  The question is just telling you the exact value of $E[X^n]$ for every $n>0$.  Those are called the *moments* of the distribution (e.g. the first moment is simply the mean).  You don't have to differentiate the m.g.f. at all: you are given all the moments and simply need to sum them (in the appropriate way according to the definition of m.g.f.) to get the m.g.f.  Then perhaps you have a table of moment generating functions for different distributions and can recognize the result in that table.

Comment: Hmm okay, I am clearly still missing something, and yes, still very confused. I understand that each E[X^n] is a moment and that the first is the mean. I am just used to being given a pdf and told to find the MGF, and if this is the reverse way I am just unsure of how to do that? By summing do you mean adding each factorial? 1! + 2! + 3! ... + n!?

Comment: I actually mean summing as Siong Thye Goh's answer has already shown.  The definition of the m.g.f. is $E[e^{tX)]$ and if you write out the Taylor series for $e^(tX)$ you can see that you can calculate this quantity (as a function of $t$) using only knowledge of all the moments of $X$.

Comment: If you're not sure what the procedure is for extracting the distribution from knowledge of the moments, then you aren't missing anything.  There isn't really a rote procedure, just as there isn't a rote procedure for figuring out the value of an arbitrary infinite sum given all the terms.  I think your expectation should be that you need to relate the clues you are given to other distributions that you already know about, rather than deducing the formula de novo.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps this might help:

$$\mathbb{E}[e^{tX}]=\mathbb{E}\left[\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(tX)^n}{n!}\right]=\sum_{n=0}^\infty t^n=\frac{1}{1-t}$$

for $|t|<1$.

Comment: I fixed a typo in this answer. Hope that it is fine (+1).

Comment: Sure, thank you very much. I tend to make silly mistakes. =)

Answer (score 3):

So $$M_X(t)=\mathsf{E}[e^{tX}]=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}t^n\frac{\mathsf{E}[X^n]}{n!}=\frac{1}{1-t}$$
The problem boils down to finding a pdf from the above $M_X(t)$.

In doing so, note that $$\begin{align}f_X(x)&=\mathcal{L}^{-1}\{M_X(-s)\}\\&=\mathcal{L}^{-1}\{\frac{1}{1+s}\}\\&=e^{-x}\end{align}$$

Thus, $$X\sim{\tt Exp}(1)$$
That is $X$ is exponentially distributed with parameter $\lambda=1$.